# Want to increment the value of counter per click of radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii2

Here is my data to which I want to increment per click of radio.

```
<span class="pull-right negative"><?= $positive ?></span>
<span class="pull-right positive"><?= $negative ?></span>
```

```js
function reviewsub() { 
  if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').val() == 0){
  } else { 
  }
```

```php
<?= $form->field($model, 'review')->inline() ->radioList( [1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'],[ 'onclick' => "reviewsub()"])->label(false) ?>
```

Dynamically I'm getting the values through variable through these span fields. But i want to increment the values onclick without reloading page. 
Please help

Comment: Are these values numeric? It would help to see the actual HTML instead of spaghetti PHP. Also, where is the radio button? Please add the JS code you attempted to solve the issue with.

Comment: please provide your js code for increment

Comment: function reviewsub(){
        if($('input[type=radio]:checked').val()==0){
        }
        else{
        }   Here it is

Comment: What about the HTML with the radio? How does the `reviewsub()` function get called?

Comment: <?=  $form->field($model, 'review')->inline()
                        ->radioList(
                            [1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'],[ 'onclick' => "reviewsub()"])->label(false) ?>  Here it is

Comment: All the values are saving successfully,  but i just want to run the counter. Like when i click to no the counter will run on negative span field

Answer (score 0):

A question, do you also have to update the number on the PHP side aswell? Like in mySQL? That would require POST/GET requests everytime you clicked the button.

A simple answer would be creating a listener for clicks. (and that requires giving the radio buttons an ID.

First create two JS variables;

```
var pozitif = <?php echo $positive; ?>;
var negatif = <?php echo $negatif; ?>;
```

Then create two buttons

```
<button onclick="pozitif++; $('#pozitif').html(pozitif);">
<button onclick="negatif++; $('#negatif').html(negatif);">
```

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

You can dinamically update the displayed number in JS as suggested by Arda.

On the other hand if you want to update the data stored in the backend too without reloading the page you might do it in jQuery with a listener and an AJAX call i.e.

```
$val = 0;
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
                 if($(this).hasClass("negative")){
                  $val--;
                 } else {
                  $val++;
                 }
                 $( "#counter" ).html( $val );

                 $.ajax({url: "update_in_backend.php",type: "POST",
      data: {val: $val}, success: function(result){
                    console.log("Updated data in backend");
                 }});
                });
```

The code above (requires inclusion of jQuery) adds a listener to the click event on the radio buttons. It has the advantage of not requiring specification of onclick in html. The $.ajax call is sending a post request to an ideal PHP document (update_in_backend.php) with the update value as argument.

You might want to move the update of the displayed value for te user inside the success callback in order to update the user visualized data only if it was actually updated server-side.